# Qt: OSX: Where to put (both file manager and exec accessible) resources?

Tags: macos, qt, resources, app-bundle

im a bit confused about the most proper way to manage resources (files and folders) needed by the application.

I make it clear: 
I have an **executable** ( developing on mac osx with qt ), and a i have a **fixed folder hierarchy**, where a bunch of configuration files are kept. Those files might be manually edited, added or delete. 
Now on windows or linux, i would just easily get those files by simply accessing parent folders, and those folders are freely accessible by any OS file manager.

**But in OSX my executable is inside the .APP bundle.**

*Then i should be able to retrieve resources from within the bundle* ( even if resources management in qt creator sucks ), but the user should also be able to open and edit the app bundle, which is not feasibl at all... and i neather want to deploy any resource manager nor put the configs in (eg.)home subfolder ( i want to keep everything together ).

Is there any solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS X terms your config files should really be in Application Support, the user can access them there. However they can also access them from the app bundle if you put them in there by right clicking and selecting View Package Contents, you can then change the files and save them.

Comment: yes of course i know about view package content, but it's not really a user friendly task :/ i'll take a look to app support. thanks.

Comment: It's probably as user friendly as storing them in Application Support, depending on the complexity of the configs it might be worth having a minimal way to edit them within the app if you're trying to keep it user friendly and keep the configs together with the binary.

Comment: i'll probably end up doing it. however i meant user friendly in a linux way.. better to change paradigm.